# Compare dates or dates with time, depending if the time is set

Tags: mysql, date, datetime

I have a `datetime` field. If the user in form enters only date, the time will be set as `00:00:00` of course, that is the way it is supposed to be.

But in mysql I need to compare this field with `now()` or with `curdate()`. If the time is set and is not `00:00:00` I need to compare only dates, if the time is other value I need to compare it with `now()`.

For example, if I use in mysql `date>=now()` and the user set only date like `2013/12/22` then the comparation will be false on `12/22` which I do not want. I would like that comparation would be false on `12/23` then, the entered date is still valid on the same date.

Now if use `date>=curdate()` then the time will be ignored if somebody set time.

One solution would be to check if time is `00:00:00` and then somehow change it to `23:59:59` for comparation.

So bottom line is, if there is `00:00:00` as time in `datetime` field, user had obviously set only date so I need to compare date to `curdate()`. If time is set to any other value I need to compare date to `now()`.

Is that doable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try this condition:

```
dt >= now()
OR 
( 
  time( dt ) = '00:00:00'
  AND 
  dt >= date( now() ) 
);
```

`dt >= now()` ==> cheks if a datetime `dt` is greather than now().

`time( dt ) = '00:00:00'` ==> checks if a time part is `00:00:00`

`date( now() )` ==> truncates a time part from `now()`, leaves only a date part.

See a demo ==> http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8609c/6